Hypotachia versus tachypsychia?
Tachypsychia (or hypotachia) is the everyday notion that "time slows down" in moments of stress or action.
This is often mentioned in sports (and indeed video games, esports), and in violence such as war battles or crime encounters, whether real or fictional. (Sometimes in film when the protagonist experiences hypotachia, it's presented as the scene being in slow motion during the couple seconds of intensity.)
(The only time I've ever experienced hypotachia (or tachypsychia) in my extremely boring life is, decades ago a couple of "teen jock" dudes jumped me at a traffic light in a road rage-ish incident. The sensation of time slowing down was completely distinct, four seconds or so seemed like a minute.)
I've always used the term hypotachia for, well, hypotachia.
But over the decades I became aware that some people use tachypsychia. And for the last say decade I've been thinking "I must ask the English list about this", and now I got round to it.
The other day in a film production setting someone used the word, the issue came to mind and hence the question.
There seems to be a tension between people (I lean this way, but I'm neutral) who think "tachypsychia" is a bit of a made-up, marketing-oriented, recent, word; and people who think hypotachia is incorrect, poorly sourced and only based on one or two usages.
(On that, I always understood hypotachia to have been "invented" so to speak, ie noticed, named, and commented on, by the US Air Force in the probably 1930s test-pilots milieu (much as "checklists" came from that milieu); of course, that could be all wrong: however I can't recall where I read or heard that.)
I can think of people I know who use only one and not the other, and vice versa.
What's the real deal on this?
Note that (even I am not so hopeless as to be unable to figure this out) the former has a tiny number of GOOGLE hits, the latter many.  One possible problem is, someone put in a wikipedia entry for the latter, which distorts everything from then on.

Google nGrams suggests hypotachia is rare to non-existent even before Wikipedia

It's not in the full OED.

But it also doesn't have "tachypsychia".

Please add definitions from reliable sources.

I've always used the term hypotachia for, well, hypotachia. In your lifetime, how many times have you used it/either? You make it sound like a regular event. Have you a sample sentence?

? tachypsychia (or hypotachia!) is just when "time appears to slow down when you're under stress" (eg during a fight, video game, war or such). (random google  https://www.thebehavioralscientist.com/glossary/tachypsychia ). there are numerous academic articles on the (wikipedia page!) of tachypsychia I've always used hypotachia interchangeably (but of course I may have just been drunk, coincidentally dealt with someone who used the wrong word, or whatever; hence the question)

Since both are very unusual words, why didn't you include the definition in your  question?

You should explain the context you want to use it in: medicine, psychology, some other academic discipline, something to do with the military, texts for the general reader, marketing material (for what I've no idea but you mention it)...

@StuartF and Grey - a pretty common use is in "e sports" or video games generally (or indeed just sports I guess).  Surely guys, you have used and heard the completely common phrase "it's like time slowed down ...", you know like in a movie when someone is attacked by the villain or such (or indeed in real life).

I’m voting to close this question because words in question are extremely specialised and would be better placed in Psychology SE, an area in which at least one of them is used.

@Fattie - no - it shows the use of tachypsychia started to appear in books then, but that it found no books at all with hypotachia.

@Henry sorry, that was a confusing typo!! Replaced:  PS Henry the graph you included is amazing; it confirms the idea that tachypsychia came in to being around WW2. TY !!!!!

Btw, the ngrams tool, as shown in the first comment, is a much better way of gauging the commonality of a term than a simple google search, since the latter can get watered down by e-commerce and other things that aren't meant as communication. It has its pitfalls too, though, and is still just a rough tool.

@AndyBonner yes, I see many great uses of that tool on here

Since you didn't give a definition of the meaning you're going for in the question, this is going to be messy.

Noun
tachypsychia (uncountable)
A neurological condition that alters the perception of time.
wiktionary.org - tachypsychia

I was unable to find definitions for hypotachia. But...
Google translate believes that hypotachia is a Slovic word that translates into English as hypotachy.
Which according to this Medical Surgical Lecture about fluid and electrolyte imbalance seems to be a

Shock like manifestation
studocu.com

Which, for all I know, makes you experience an altered perception of time. Yeah, messy.
If you’re proposed usage needs a word that communicates the feeling of time slowing down I think the clear winner here is tachypsychia.
Nothing I found about hypotachia explicitly means you feel time slowing down. It just described shock.
What did you think either of these meant?
Transliterations can mess with spelling. Are you sure you spelled hypotachia the way English speakers do?
These questions are best answered by updating the question. Not with comments.

@Fattie It's easy to find definitions of "tachypsychia," but not of "hypotachia." The only uses I can find of "hypotachia" are (1) Reddit posts by a user who I believe is you, and (2) a made-up word in a nursing textbook invented as a wrong answer to a multiple choice question.

Yes, as mentioned I think this answer by CO basically solves the question...

@alphabet would love to see links for your (1) and (2).
